# Determining if all elements in array A are present in array B

Tags: javascript

So this is the code:

```
var array_A = [1,2,4];
var array_B = [1,2,3,4];
```

I need a function that for the case above will print TRUE. Because

```
1,2 and 4
```

are present in array_B.

The function will print FALSE if the declaration is as following:

```
var array_A = [1,2,4,5];
var array_B = [1,2,3,4];
```

Because

```
"5"
```

is not present in array_B.

I guess this is quite easy to accomplish with lodash or underscore. But could not find exactly what I was looking for. Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array every and indexOf:

```js
var array_A = [1,2,4];
var array_B = [1,2,3,4];

var result = array_A.every(el => array_B.indexOf(el) !== -1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var array_A = [1, 2, 4],
    array_B = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = array_A.every(a => array_B.includes(a));

console.log(result);
```